# Can I pass a query string through base_url function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to pass a query string through base_url() function in codeigniter?

I would like to add ?login=1 to the base url which user arrives at after being redirected in this function:

```
redirect(base_url());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with simple string concatenation.

```
redirect(base_url().'?login=1');
```

and as per the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html), you can indeed pass a string into the `base_url()` function:

```
redirect(base_url('?login=1'));
```

Although it isn't designed for this purpose - it's supposed to be used for segments so functionality with a query string passed into the function isn't guaranteed.